# Calculating sum using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm beginner on AngularJs and I have a difficult to show the sum of two numbers. The first script work perfectly :

```
<div>
   <p><input type="text" ng-model="price1" /> <strong>{{price1}}</strong></p>
   <p><input type="text" ng-model="price2" /> <strong>{{price2}}</strong></p>
   <p><strong>{{total = (price1 * 1 + price2 * 1) }}</strong></p>
</div>
```

But when I try to test this using a controller, like this :

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <p><input type="text" ng-model="price1" /> <strong>{{price1}}</strong></p>
   <p><input type="text" ng-model="price2" /> <strong>{{price2}}</strong></p>
   <p><strong>{{total}}</strong></p>
</div>
<script>
   var app = angular.module('firstApp', []);
   app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.total = ($scope.price1  + $scope.price2);
   }]);
</script>
```

I have no result, just a NaN value.
I have no idea what happen !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. The variables `$scope.price1` and `$scope.price2` are not defined
   once the controller is initialized. Arithmetical operation using
   `undefined` value produces `NaN` as the result.
2. You compute the
   `$scope.total` just once. Its result is not updated on change of
   `$scope.price1` or `$scope.price2`
3. In the inputs you should use `type="number"` not `type="text"` then the values of `$scope.price1` and `$scope.price2` will be parsed and summed up as numbers. In your code they are concatenated as strings.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.price1 = 1;
  $scope.price2 = 2;
  
  $scope.getTotal = function() {
    return $scope.price1 + $scope.price2;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <p><input type="number" ng-model="price1" /> <strong>{{price1}}</strong></p>
   <p><input type="number" ng-model="price2" /> <strong>{{price2}}</strong></p>
   <p><strong>{{getTotal()}}</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to set default values? Is it saying NaN because you haven't entered anything in the input boxes?

Try initializing the variables in the controller above the total calculation.

```
$scope.price1 = 0;
$scope.price2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The values are undefined when you call the sum, just give them an initial value

```
$scope.price1 = 1;
$scope.price2 = 2;
$scope.total = ($scope.price1  + $scope.price2);
```

What you are doing is equals to:

```
$scope.total = ($scope.price1  + $scope.price2);
$scope.total = (undefined  + undefined); //equals to NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it but I have to give a value in my controller for price1 and price2, like that :

```
<script>
   var app = angular.module('firstApp', []);
   app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.price1 = 1;
      $scope.price2 = 2;
      $scope.total = ($scope.price1 + $scope.price2);
   }]);
</script>
```

But I have two input. I want to use them like a calculator, put a value into them and see the result.